# Obtain the first entry of JSON

Tags: php, json, decode

I have this JSON in a URL:

```
{"success":true,"rgInventory":{"6073259621":{"id":"6073259621","classid":"1660549198","instanceid":"188530139","amount":"1","pos":1}}}
```

I need obtain the first entry after `rgInventory`. The problem is the problem is that suppose that I don't know that there are `"6073259621"`. How I can obtain it without know what there?

I try this but don't work:

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$obj2 = json_decode(json_encode($obj['rgInventory']), true);
$obj3 = json_decode(json_encode($obj2), true); 
echo $obj3;
```

Comment: Get the keys with `array_keys()` and the use that to get the first key and then you have your key.

Comment: No need to decode multiple times. Once you have decoded the first time you will have an array you can traverse.

Comment: Do you actually want to return `6073259621` or the array that it contains?

Comment: @AbraCadaver both if it's possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to get the key and the value (array) using [each()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

list($key, $val) = each($data['rgInventory']);

echo $key;
print_r($val);
```

Yields:

```
6073259621
Array
(
    [id] => 6073259621
    [classid] => 1660549198
    [instanceid] => 188530139
    [amount] => 1
    [pos] => 1
)
```

But I just noticed that the `id` is the same as the key, so not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

if the JSON string is valid and like below

```
{ "success":true,
  "rgInventory":{
      "6073259621":{
          "id":"6073259621",
          "classid":"1660549198",
          "instanceid":"188530139",
          "amount":"1",
          "pos":1
       }
    }
}
```

> get the decode in $obj like

```
  $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

> then your first entry would be

```
 echo array_keys($obj['rgInventory'])[0];
```

> to understand it clearly and to know where is "6073259621"

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
var_dump($obj);
```

> also note the difference

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

the **output** would be ..

```
// decode as object
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}

// decode as array
array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have the JSON decoded with this:

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

You can get the first item from `rgInventory`, regardless of what its key is, using [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

```
$first_entry = reset($obj['rgInventory']);
```